# Listview becomes disabled by default

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview whose adapter is used with 2 textviews and one imageview.

But I can't click any item in the listview. The listview becomes grayed out at runtime. I have set O`nItemCLickListener` for the listview but it still doesn't work.

```
m_lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
         ((JListAdapter)arg0.getAdapter()).setSelView(arg1);
         ListView lv=(ListView)arg0;
         TextView v=(TextView)lv.getChildAt(arg2);
         String s=(String) v.getText();
         Toast.makeText(m_context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the xml for listview's items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_txt"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/lvitem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="@string/dummy_txt"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lv_datetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_lv_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="@string/dummy_txt"
        android:textSize="7sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in your xml list view add this property android:clickable="true"

Comment: Post your XML you use for each list item

Comment: I disabled all focuses (set to false) of textviews, imageview in the adapter xml and also turn on clickable (true) for the listview but it's still the same being disabled

Comment: @user3431664 try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the relativelayout

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you but it's still ineffective

Comment: @user3431664 does the app crash. Comment everything in onItemClick and just display a toast and see if it works

Comment: @Raghunandan no crash at all, only the whole listview is disabled, since I have a long list of item in there, I can only drag it up and down (vertical scrollbar available), selecting each item is impossible. Because it is disabled, onclickitem doesn't work.

Comment: @user3431664 what happens when you click on list item. Do you any of the views taking focus. i see nothing wrong.

Comment: @Raghunandan nothing happens, that listview is allocated in one relative layout, by other views do you mean other layouts in the same layout wrapper ? The listview is all just that, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to edit your xml file as Below:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_txt"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/lvitem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="@string/dummy_txt"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lv_datetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_lv_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/dummy_txt"
        android:textSize="7sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```